# Returning string with an attribute in it

Tags: ruby, tdd

I have this ruby code for my class player and my class game, I'm working in the tennis kata.

```
class Player
  def score
    if @player_one.points <3 and @player_two.points<3
        "#{@player_one.score} #{@player_two.score}"
    elsif @player_one.points == @player_two.points
        "#{@player_one.score} iguales"
    end

    if @player_one.points == 3 and @player_two.points == 3
        'deuce'
    elsif (@player_one.points == @player_two.points + 1) and (@player_two.points >=3)
        "Ventaja #{@player_one.name}"
    elsif (@player_one.points >= 4) and (@player_one.points >= (@player_two.points + 2))
        "Game #{@player_one.name}"
    end
  end
end
```

And this test can't pass, all the other tests that had already passed aren't here.

```
it 'return 30-iguales when both players have 2 points scored' do
    player_one = Player.new
    player_two = Player.new

    game = TennisGame.new(player_one, player_two)
    player_one.wins_point
    player_one.wins_point

    player_two.wins_point
    player_two.wins_point
    expect(game.score).to eq("30 iguales")
  end
```

The error that I got is that "30 iguales" are expected but got `nil`.
All my other tests have passed, but in this one fails, and I cant solve the problem.

Comment: Please explain at the beginning what your code is intended to do. Most readers won't understand "class game" and "class player".

Answer (score 0):

Ruby methods will return the last evaluated expression even without an explicit `return` statement, and I take it that’s what you’re going for here. The problem is that for the test data the method will evaluate `"#{@player_one.score} iguales"`, but then continue on evaluating the second `if` statement, and falling all the way through it to return `nil`.

Your options to fix are:

1. Make the whole thing a single `if` statement instead of two. Or:
2. Explicitly return the value of each possible  string.